# crm2011 plugin call js function

Tags: javascript, plugins, call, dynamics-crm-2011

How can I run JavaScript function from appropriate web resource with a plugin in CRM2011.

I couldn't find any information on the Internet. Most of the resources describes how to trigger plugin from JS, but not opposite.

Here's JS code taht is copying the notes to the description field.
When save is clicked. you can see that the data is correctly display in a description field. However if you press save and close and open form again the description field will be empty.
I thought that the reason for that is that the JS executed after safe event but later tests descovered that it's false. Could someone point out an error in this JS code which cause that data is not saving? 
Or give a suggestion how's write a plugin which is retrieving data from related entity and writes it into field in the form. thanx

[image]

```
function copyNotes()
 {
// CLEAR DESCRIPTION FIELD
alert("JS");
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("description").setValue('');
// GET ID OF THE CASE AND CLEAN IT AND GET URL for oData stuff
//THEN CALL RETRIEVE FUNCTION
    var caseID = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
    caseID = caseID.replace('{', '').replace('}', '');
    var oDataPath = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl() + "/xrmservices/2011/organizationdata.svc";
    ODataPath = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl() + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc";
    retrieveRecord(caseID);
}
// CREATE AN HTTP REQUEST AND SEND IT
function retrieveRecord(Id) {

var retrieveReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
retrieveReq.open("GET", ODataPath + "/AnnotationSet?$filter=ObjectId/Id" + " eq (guid'" + Id + "')", true);

retrieveReq.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
retrieveReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
retrieveReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
// THIS HANDLES A CALLBACK 
        retrieveReqCallBack(this);
    };
    retrieveReq.send();
}

function retrieveReqCallBack(retrieveReq) {
    if (retrieveReq.readyState == 4 /* complete */  )
 {
        if (retrieveReq.status == 200) {
            //Success
            var retrieved = this.parent.JSON.parse(retrieveReq.responseText).d;
// ITERATE THROUGH THE NOTES FOR THIS CASE
            for (var i = 0; i < retrieved.results.length; i++) {
// IF IS AN EMPTY FIELD ADD 'case details:'
                if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("description").getValue() == null || Xrm.Page.getAttribute("description").getValue() == 'null') {
                    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("description").setValue('Case details:');
                }
                // BOF PARSE DATE
                var date = retrieved.results[i].CreatedOn;
                date = new Date(parseInt(date.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), 10));
                // EOF PARSE DATE
                var newtext = "--------------------\r\n" + "Created by: " + retrieved.results[i].CreatedBy.Name + " - " + date + "\r\n" + retrieved.results[i].NoteText + "\r\n--------------------\r\n";
                var text = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("description").getValue() + "\r\n" + newtext;
                Xrm.Page.getAttribute("description").setValue(text);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish that a plugin needs to update javascript on the client from the server?

Comment: the plugin needs to run one function from js web resource. Problem is that I need to make this function run before onSave event, which I don't know how and I think that's impossible. The only was I could think of is to write a plugin which will run JS script. Otherwise I feel like I have to replicate behavour of the js function in the plugin.

Comment: Why can't your javascript run in the OnSave event of the form?

Comment: It can. But as I see it fires after onSave even. Firstly form saves and that JS runs. I need it to be executed before form saves. Run onLoad is not handy for me as well. Actually I need to run it on change of another entity which is related to it and embedded in the form, but this entity is a system one and I can't modify it or assign JS on change of particular field in that entity

Comment: The OnSave Javascript event runs before the actual Database update / plugin execution occurs.

Comment: Ok thanx. I ll check. May be I need to debug a JS as well. But for example when I assign it on onSave event. When I press save button it works. When I press save and close it doesn't work. My conclusion was that it's happening because JS runs after save event

Comment: That's strange. *save-close* is supposed to perform the same operation as *save*, so the plugin should be fired anyway. How is it registered? And do I dare to ask - is the JS large? Maybe we could take a look at it. Maybe.

Comment: Yes, that's why I was surprised and suggest that's executing after save event. I've attached an image and piece of JS related to copying data. Entire JS not that big (16kb). This JS is executing onSave of the form, which was specified in form properties/events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no supported way to call back to the client from the server from within the plugin.  I'm also not aware of any unsupported way.

I don't think this question even makes sense.  Plugin's only trigger when there has been a CRUD operation of some sort.  Any CRUD operation triggered by the GUI will result in a refresh of the entity any way.  You could perform an update via javascript and an Odata call, but then once the plugin has finished, you can run whatever javascript you'd like to run.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. That's why i couldn't find anything

Answer (score 2):

There's no (reasonable) way to do that.

The reason for that is the fact that plugin is a server-size executed thingy. It can't even assume there's a GUI. (Of course, we know there is but generally, a server-size code can't interact with the GUI directly).

JavaScript is client-side code and a client assumes a server. That's (roughly) why JS can call a plugin (although I wouldn't put it that way) but not the other way around.

I've never had a need of such an operation so I'm curious as to what your task is. Are you asking of pure, academic interest or is it a part of a design? Perhaps there's a better way to reach your goal?

Comment: I have a form. On this form I have a section where users can add a notes (annotations). I have a JS that has already written. One function of this JS is copying some parameters from the notes to another field on this form. I didn't want to touch this JS, and being absolute newbie in C# and plugins stuff I touhgt that write a plugin which triggers JS would be easier that write a plugin which is accessing Entities copying data and inserting it in a different place. That is why I asked about this solution. However now I as see I have to do everything in a plugin

Comment: @AlexeyOmelchenko I really dig the way you're thinking. You're as pragmatic as my colleague Rickard, whom I respect a lot for that very property. I really wish that it'd be possible to do what you suggested. Sadly, I don't think it is. Never the less, keep figuring in those trails because it's the cheapest way for the customer. +1 for that.

Comment: Also, please check one of the replies as an answer. It's not the answer you'd like but non the less, that **is** the answer. Suggestably, you should check the reply by @Daryl because he was quicker to respond by three hours. Darn Texans!   :)

Comment: Ok thanx. I've replied to him.

Comment: @AlexeyOmelchenko I didn't me that you need to reply. I meant that you should pick one of the answers and "check" it as done (left side a checky-thing will turn green when you click it. You're also encouraged to vote up/down the answers (and questions) you like in general by clicking the arrows above/below the number on the left side. That's the correct way of saying "thanks" on Stack Overflow.   :)

Comment: oh ok i didn't know about this "check" thing. And yeah, i'd love to rate the answers, but need to gain more reputation for it.

Comment: @AlexeyOmelchenko I think you're good to do that by now. Try again.